# Selenium: Firefox doesn't update IWebElement state after Click action

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a problem with Selenium not refreshing the state of a button object when it's clicked. The web page toggles the text of the button from "On" to "Off" when you click it. However, in Firefox, if you get the text after clicking, you get the original rather than the current text. In Chrome, it works fine. Haven't tried IE yet.
Is there a way (without having to find the widget on the page again) to refresh the internal state? Or, am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste time here, but it turned out to be a program bug. :(

Comment: At least you know that Selenium is working as intended, and is helping to find bugs in your application :)